# Arrange color in fragment shader without texture coordinates depending on fragment position

Tags: c++, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, fragment-shader

I need to draw a rectangle in OpenGL ES 2.0 but to arrange color for rectangle in fragment shader. I will draw two triangles to represent the rectangle. This is similar to texture mapping but without the texture coordinates. What would be ideal is to take a specific pixel and calculate its position. On the other side there is an array containing **16** elements of **0**s and **1**s. The pixel is calculated and it is compared to the arrays element at the same location (this is possible if you take remainder of division with **16** since it will return **0** - **15**). If the element in corresponding array's index is **1**, that pixel will be colored using a specific color from a fragment shader attribute, otherwise it will not be colored.

#### The following diagram illustrates the problem:

[image: Picture as a model for the problem]

#### This is my problem

The array is passed as uniform value to fragment shader and it seems that it is not passed correctly:

The following is the code where uniform value is passed to fragment shader:

```
void GeometryEngine::drawLineGeometry(QGLShaderProgram *program)
{

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);

    // Bind attribute position in vertex shader to the program
    int vertexLocation = program->attributeLocation("position");
    program->enableAttributeArray(vertexLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    const int array[16] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};


    int arrayLocation = program->attributeLocation("array");
    program->setUniformValueArray(arrayLocation, array, 16);
    // Draw triangles (6 points)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
uniform int array[16];

void main()
{

     gl_FragColor = vec4(array[0], 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

   /* int index = int(mod(gl_FragCoord.x, 16.0));
    if( array[index] == 1 )
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    else
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   */
}
```

Commented lines should create specific color for the fragments, but I cannot test this part because the array is not passed correctly. The rectangle is black, instead of red (array[0] is 1, not 0).

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do. What part are you stuck on? Please post the code you have so far and point out where you need help.

Comment: If I correctly understand what you're trying to do, I would still pass something similar to texture coordinates into the fragment shader. This doesn't mean that you actually have to use texturing. You can calculate the desired color based on the "texture coordinates" and your lookup table. People sometimes call this a "procedural texture". You could potentially use `gl_FragCoord`, but that is in units of widow coordinates if you read it in the fragment shader. If that lets you do what you want, that will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I cannot use any kind of texturing coordinates. i need to compare fragments of my rectangle with lookup table. I have the code which makes the rectangle but in fragment shader I need to take the pixels and compare to the lookup table. That is my problem.

Comment: Hi, IMHO, every time I have had problems with uniform was depending on the way I have been passing/attaching values or getting the uniform location. Can you please share the code used for "setUniformValueArray" to better understand where the problem is?